# variable transformation to make equation become standard heat equation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

let $b\in\mathbb{R},k>0$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be given. Derive a representative formula for solutions of the Cauchy problem with initial data $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ of the equation
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-k\Delta u=aDu+bu$$
I want to solve this with some suitable variable transformation to make this equation become a standard heat equation, but I have some difficulty in finding it.
I know that for the equation of the form $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\Delta u+cu=0$$
we can apply $v=u\cdot e^{ct}$ but what about the $aDu$?
I have an idea that assume $v=u(\sqrt{k}x,t)\cdot e^{\alpha t+\beta x}$, then by choose some suitable $\alpha,\beta$ I can get the equation I want. Can someone help me check my idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define $v(x,t)=u(\sqrt{k}x-at,t)\cdot e^{-bt}$
by calculation we have that 
$v_t=-aDu(\sqrt{k}x-at,t)e^{-bt}-bu(\sqrt{k}x-at,t)e^{-bt}+u_t(\sqrt{k}x-at,t)e^{-bt}$
$v_{x_i}=\sqrt{k}u_{x_i}(\sqrt{k}x-at,t)e^{-bt}$
$v_{x_ix_i}=ku_{x_ix_i}(\sqrt{k}x-at,t)e^{-bt}$
therefore $$v_t-\Delta v=\left[u_t(\sqrt{k}x-at,t)-\Delta u(\sqrt{k}x-at,t)-aDu(\sqrt{k}x-at,t)-bu(\sqrt{k}x-at,t)\right]e^{-bt}=0$$
hence $v$ is a solution to the standard heat equation
then apply the representative formual
$$v(x,t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x-y,t)v(y,0)dy$$
therefore $u(x,t)=v(\frac{x-at}{\sqrt{k}},t)e^{bt}$ which is
$$u(x,t)=e^{bt}\cdot\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(\frac{x-at}{\sqrt{k}}-y,t)u(y,0)dy$$